# prevent resizing of parent by child

Tags: reactjs, responsive, bootstrap-5

I allow myself to post my problem because I can't find a solution and I'm starting to pull my hair out.

I would like to make my second column the same height as my first column.

Concern is that since the content is larger than the initial size, it enlarges the parent div and therefore increases the content of the page.

I specify that I use Boostrap 5

My code:

```
    <div className="row g-2">
        <div className="col-md-5">
            <div className='border border-primary border-4 bg-secondary' style={{ height: 400 + "px" }}></div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-7">
            <div className='border border-primary border-4 bg-dark p-2 h-100 overflow-auto'>
                <div className="bg-danger" style={{ height: 800 + "px" }}>
                    <span className="text-white fs-1">Hello World </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[The problem in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzsOw.png)

[Here is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLTf3.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding fixed height to parent element can be a solution. Also don't forget [overflow class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/overflow/) to parent.

```
     <div className="row g-2 overflow-hidden" style={{ height: '400px' }}>
        <div className="col-md-5">
          <div
            className="border border-primary border-4 bg-secondary"
            style={{ height: 400 + 'px' }}
          ></div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-7">
          <div className="border border-primary border-4 bg-dark p-2 h-100 overflow-auto">
            <div className="bg-danger" style={{ height: 800 + 'px' }}>
              <span className="text-white fs-1">Hello World </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Update:

> What I'm really looking for is that column two is the same height as column one (its height will be automatic with the content).

You can achieve this by making second column `relative` and its child `absolute`. Also add top, bottom, left and right to `0`

```
      <div className="row g-2">
        <div className="col-md-5">
          <div
            className="border border-primary border-4 bg-secondary"
            style={{ height: 400 + 'px' }}
          ></div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-7 position-relative">
          <div className="border position-absolute top-0 start-0 end-0 bottom-0 border-primary border-4 bg-dark p-2 h-100 overflow-auto">
            <div className="bg-danger" style={{ height: 800 + 'px' }}>
              <span className="text-white fs-1">Hello World </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Your solution may be interesting but when I define the precise height to the column it is for the example.

What I'm really looking for is that column two is the same height as column one (its height will be automatic with the content).